# How do I prevent filtering of parent when adding a filter to a relationship?

Tags: views

I have a view of users which includes a relationship to a multi-value paragraph field. I’m adding a filter to the paragraph if *field_current* is set to true, to show only the current paragraph. But the side effect of this is that users are not included in the view if a current paragraph doesn't exist.

Is there any way to avoid filtering out the users, and just show empty fields if there isn't a current paragraph?

Comment: I would build a field formatter that only shows child paragraphs when the checkbox is checked. Then I would just build a normal view and set that field to use my formatter - no relationship needed.

Comment: You mean using this module? https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_formatter Does it play well with data export?

Comment: Oh I think you mean a custom formatter like this https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-field-formatter - think this could work, thanks!

Comment: It works! If you add an answer I'll accept it :)